# I believe this problem has a typo, but I want to make sure before telling my teacher. Does it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

An amphitheater charges $74$ dollars for each seat in Section A, $59$ dollars for each seat in Section B, and $28$ dollars for each lawn seat. There are three times as many seats in Section B as in Section A. The revenue from selling all $13,000$ seats is $\$503,000$. Let $x$ be the number of seats in A, $y$ be the number of seats in B, and $z$ be the number of lawn seats. Which system of equations represents the situation?

There are 2 answers to the question, the problem is multiple choice. The first answer is below:

$$y=3x$$

$$x+y+z=503,000$$

$$74x+59y+28z=13,000$$

The second:

$$y=3x$$

$$x+y+z=13,000$$

$$74x+59y+28z=503,000$$

Wouldn't the correct answer be:

$$x=3y$$

$$x+y+z=13,000$$

$$74x+59y+28z=503,00$$

Comment: What's the difference between the first and the second answer?

Comment: in the first, $x+y+z=503,000$

in the second, $x+y+z=13,000$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct.

$y=3x$ means that $y$ is three times as large as $x$. For example, if there are $x=2$ section A seats, then there are $y=3x=6$ section B seats, so we have here that there are three times as many seats in section B as in section A.

Comment: Wow... that's embarrassing on my part. How did I not realize that? I've been sitting here blanking for like 20 minutes trying to wrap my head around $$y=3x$$